# List options without typing on autocomplete

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to show options when user clicks to the input field instead of showing after typing at least one matching character?

Autocomplete starts showing the options after user types one character but it is hard to guess for new users what's the possible options for related field.

Comment: If you can show the options it suggests autocomplete is not the right choice for the field. Autocomplete is best suited to cases where there are too many options to display. So a simple select with or without chosen (as per @Jdrupal answer) sounds like a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is showing the field as a select list and use the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module to be able to search through the options.

> By default the module will automatically apply itself to any select elements that have more than 20 options, which is a reasonable default for which having Chosen will be useful. To change or disable this automatic enhancement, you can change the selectors (or remove all selectors) from the *Apply Chosen to the following elements* field on the Chosen administration page.
> You can force enable/disable Chosen for certain field widgets: Select list (for both list and date fields), and [Select (or other) list](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other). If you have a field using one of these widgets, in the field settings, you will find a *Apply Chosen to the select fields in this widget?* option with three values: Apply, Do not apply, or No preference (which will fall back to using the automatic application).